# Sql connection with dynamic ip

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm wondering if i can create an sql connection which connects with dynamic ip.
Example i wrote in google "What Is My IP Address?" And i took an ip 43.22.33.919

Can i create a connection which will connect in this ip?
Something like this:

```
Data Source= 43.22.33.919,1433;Initial Catalog=xxx;user ID=xxx;Password=xxx
```

Should i use dynamic tcp/ports? How will configure this?

Comment: Do you have "white" IP address? What about NAT? Do your internet provider allows opening certain ports?

Comment: What is white ip? What port should i open in my router?

Comment: it short. Yes you can. But there are lots of others configuration and setup required on your Router, firewall etc

Comment: Ok i made fordward my ip into router. My router fordward port is 8081. My local ip port is 1433. Which of them i will use? Data Source= 43.22.33.919,1433;Initial Catalog=xxx;user ID=xxx;Password=xxx or Data Source= 43.22.33.919,8081;Initial Catalog=xxx;user ID=xxx;Password=xxx

Comment: Yes off course you can. Please follow this [link](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/62165/i-cant-connect-to-my-servers-sql-database-via-an-ip-address)